# Mongodb sort documents based on a dynamic field and a static field

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to write a query so that when fetching a list of users, the users are sorted in a way that depends on two fields.

The first is a distance field that is calculated using the $geoNear query.
The second field is a "popularity" field on the user document.

For simplicity, I would like to sort by a "weight" algorithm where the weight is `0.7 * distance + 0.3 * popularity`.

How would I implement something in mongodb? Is this even possible to be done efficiently in mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this using the `aggregation` pipeline. You could have separate stages to handle this, e.g. perform the geospatial query and store the computed distance, then perform a projection to compute the `weight`, and finally perform a `sort` on the newly-generated `weight` field.

As for doing this efficiently, that's just not going to happen. Efficiency can only occur when you have a set of known values, and the values you want are going to be unknown until they're computed at runtime. Just ensure that your `$geoNear` query returns a subset of documents that won't be problematic in size and you should be fine.